R shiny + google map: Pin (marker) doesn't load when using googleway::google_map_update()
I have an app that uses googleway to work with google maps api. It uses a callback javascript function to handle the autocompletion functionality from google maps api (see reprex below). At start it loads a map and a textbox above it with a search button. That loads fine. The problem happens when one searches an address and after pressing the search button the map updates but it doesn't place the marker with the red pin. The errors are noticeable on the browser console and they look like this:

If the page is reloaded a second time, then the app works as expected when searching for an address the map updates and a marker is placed, like below:

I have tried changing the way the libraries are loaded, from the googleway google_map function to the js loading script in the header. What I expect is the map to show the pin from the first search.
I have built a reprex code that can show the problem. It has to be run with the browser's developer tools open and option 'Disable cache' on from the network menu so it can simulate the first time the app loads.
library(shiny)
library(googleway)

key <- "you key"
set_key(key = key)
#google_keys()

ui <- shiny::basicPage(
  
  div(
    textInput(inputId = "my_address", label = "Type An Address")
    ,textOutput(outputId = "full_address")
    ,actionButton(inputId = "btn", "Search")
    ,HTML(paste0(" <script> 
                function initAutocomplete() {

                 var autocomplete =   new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('my_address'),{types: ['geocode']});
                 autocomplete.setFields(['address_components', 'formatted_address',  'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);
                 autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                 var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                 if (!place.geometry) {
                 return;
                 }

                 var addressPretty = place.formatted_address;
                 var address = '';
                 if (place.address_components) {
                 address = [
                 (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[3] && place.address_components[3].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[4] && place.address_components[4].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[5] && place.address_components[5].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[6] && place.address_components[6].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[7] && place.address_components[7].short_name || '')
                 ].join(' ');
                 }
                 var address_number =''
                 address_number = [(place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || '')]
                 var coords = place.geometry.location;
                 //console.log(address);
                 Shiny.onInputChange('jsValue', address);
                 Shiny.onInputChange('jsValueAddressNumber', address_number);
                 Shiny.onInputChange('jsValuePretty', addressPretty);
                 Shiny.onInputChange('jsValueCoords', coords);});}
                 </script> 
                 <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=", key,"&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete' async defer=NA></script>"))
    ,google_mapOutput(outputId = "my_map")
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  my_address <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$jsValueAddressNumber)){
      if(length(grep(pattern = input$jsValueAddressNumber, x = input$jsValuePretty ))==0){
        final_address<- c(input$jsValueAddressNumber, input$jsValuePretty)
      } else{
        final_address<- input$jsValuePretty
      }
      final_address
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    # browser()
    my_address <- my_address()
    not_a_df <- google_geocode(address = my_address)
    my_coords <- geocode_coordinates(not_a_df)
    my_coords <- data.frame(lat = as.numeric(my_coords$lat[1]), lng = as.numeric(my_coords$lng[1]))
    
    googleway::google_map_update(map_id = "my_map") %>%
      # clear_markers() %>%
      googleway::add_markers(
        data = my_coords,
        lat = "lat",
        lon = "lng",
        update_map_view = T
      ) %>% 
      googleway::google_map_view(location = c(my_coords$lat, my_coords$lng), zoom = 19)
  })
  
  output$full_address <- renderText({
    if(!is.null(my_address())){
      my_address()
    }
  })
  
  output$my_map <- renderGoogle_map({
    google_map(
      location = c(-27.481080541187133, 153.0122871294947),
      zoom = 16,
      map_type_control = FALSE,
      zoom_control = FALSE,
      street_view_control = FALSE
    ) 
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Any ideas are much appreciated.

this was solved in a github issue
